# How to get two separate aggregate reports for two suite classes using Serenity BDD with cucumber?

Tags: maven, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I'm using Serenity BDD using java with cucumber. In the project, there are separate Test Runner classes for each feature file and then two suites where these runners are divided. The suite classes look like this

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
FeatureATestRunner.class, 
FeatureBTestRunner.class
})
public class SuiteATestSuite {}
---------------------------------------
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
FeatureCTestRunner.class, 
FeatureDTestRunner.class
})
public class SuiteBTestSuite {}
```

I run both the suites in parallel and want two separate aggregate reports for each suite. Currently, with the following configuration on pom.xml file, only one aggregate report is generated that contains results of both suites.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.15</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

What changes do I need to do to get separate aggregate report for both these Test Suites?